# Authorization with multiple authentication schemes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, authorization

I'm using [this way of adding multiple authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x#use-multiple-authentication-schemes) in my ASP.NET Core API (v2.1)

Here is my code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    const string OtherSchema = "MyOtherSchema";

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = GetFirstTokenValidationParameters();
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(OtherSchema, options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = GetSecondTokenValidationParameters();
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy =
            new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OtherSchema)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
    });
```

And I decorated my endpoints with `[Authorize]` attribute.
Now the problem is just the default schema's token authorized (first) and MyOtherSchema's token is unauthorized (second).

Even if I swap the schemes in `AddJwtBearer`s still default schema's token authorized (second) and MyOtherSchema's token is unauthorized (first).

What I missed?

Comment: It won't validate all your authentication schemes at once. Why don't you merge these schemes to one if you need criteria from both?

Comment: Can you show how you check whether each scheme was authenticated?